# Randomly displaying an element of a set

Tags: pdf, animations, random

Given a set of words I want to be able to produce a PDF file such that a press of a button causes a random word from the set to be displayed.

Stylish display: A wheel (somewhat similar to the wheel of "Wheel of Fortune") turns and when it stops the name that is pointed to by an arrow is the choice. Any ideas for an interesting display is welcome.

Context:

To motivate my students to participate I have divided my class into teams. I want to randomly draw the name of a team to come to blackboard to solve a homework problem.  So, the application of this file will be that I will put the team names on the wheel and by turning the wheel choose a random presenter.

A somewhat similar question has been [answered here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541554/making-letters-of-a-word-appear-in-random-order/541626?noredirect=1#comment1368911_541626).

Comment: Only with JavaScript in PDF. That's doable with LaTeX, but not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Even *with* the revision, this seems highly dependent on the viewer as well as non-LaTeX-related content (JavaScript).

Comment: @Werner  I noticed that many browser-based PDF readers do not work well with PDF files containing JavaScript, this includes Chrome and FireFox and Adobe Reader for Iphone. However Internet Explorer seems to work on my files.  What is the learning path from LaTeX to LaTeX+JavaScript? I have seen [this](http://www.pdfill.com/download/AcroJS.pdf) but not sure if that is a good start.

Comment: @Maesumi: AcroTeX's [`insdljs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/insdljs) might be a start...